# Error while passing a number array with DELETE request angular 5

Tags: node.js, angular5, http-delete

```
deleteTemplates(templateIds : number[]): Observable<any> {
    console.log("in service");
    const params = {
       "templateIds": templateIds
    }
    return this.http.delete<Template>(this.apiUrl + 'template', templateIds);
}
```

**This is my code**

and I am getting a compile error

> *error TS2559: Type 'number' has no properties in common with type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.*

I need to pass this list of ids to API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"delete" does not take any body parameter as input so your input "templateIds" is getting mapped to options input field which is used as header and type of options is RequestOptionsArgs that is why you are getting error,

if you want to pass "list of ids to API" pass them as query param appended in url after ? and parse these ids at API side.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Actually, i was trying to hit a Spring API which supports body parameters.